# Rsync 8 Devices nightly - all files come in but nothing goes out

Tags: rsync

I have 8 devices.
One is the 'hub' and 7 'remote'.
Each of the devices is at different Physical location, and I am connected a hub and spoke VPN configuration, all remote sites can access the Hub but not each other.
There are well over 100,000 files/folders in my sync.

All RSYNC is run from the Hub (SITE0)

**NOTE:  Have used %SITE#% as a placeholder for the IP of the actual unit.  I just removed them because they were unneeded for this. I actually have an ip in the real script.**

I have setup Rsync to do the following:

MWF = Monday Wednesday Friday. (TH = Tuesday Thursday)
I Sync Site1/Site2/Site3/Site4/Site5/Site6/Site7 INbound to the 'Hub' using this command:  (where *%SiteN%* = the IP of the actual unit)

```
rsync -vzar --size-only --no-g --no-times  rsync://*%SiteN%*/Image/* /data/Image >> /data/Logs/$foo
```

(this contain the >> /data/Logs/$foo I have it write a log for review)

All of these always seem to work, that is new files are received by the 'HUB'.

After the INBOUND is complete I send outbound to 3 of the units (Site1/Site2/Site3) using this script.

```
rsync -vzar --size-only --no-g --no-times --exclude "SubFolder1/" --exclude "Subfolder2/"  /data/Image/* rsync://*%SITEN%*/Image >> /data/Logs/$foo
```

This is where I have my issue. I get the following in my logs.

Calling HUB Outbound

```
rsync Started HUB->Site3 Thu Mar 28 05:32:00 EDT 2019
sending incremental file list
rsync Stopped HUB->Sit3 Thu Mar 28 05:53:39 EDT 2019
```

Calling Site1 Outbound

```
rsync Started Hub->Site1 Thu Mar 28 05:53:39 EDT 2019
sending incremental file list
rsync Stopped Hub->Site1 Thu Mar 28 06:08:41 EDT 2019
```

Calling Site2 Outbound

```
rsync Started HUB->Site2 Thu Mar 28 06:08:41 EDT 2019
sending incremental file list
rsync Stopped HUB->Site2 Thu Mar 28 06:23:46 EDT 2019
```

=======
But if I run the OUTBOUND script(s) manually in the AM, it runs without fail.

What am I doing wrong?  Does Rsync think it does not need to update changes because I did an INBOUND earlier? I had thought this before and that is why I broke the scripts out to unique scripts called by a 'master' (SEE BELOW) in hopes that if there was some issue with RSYNC and memory.

It is interesting that on T-H I run a different set of scripts, that reverse the MWF, (Site1/Site2/Site3 inbound and all OUTBOUND) and I get the same results with Site1/Site2/Site3.

The primary difference I see between them is possibly the RSYNC version.
On the HUB and Site1/Site2/Site3 the Rsycn version is 3.1.3
on the others it is 3.0.9

Any help will be appreciated.

Full discloser:
I have a "master script" that calls individual scripts to run the required Rsync. This was done to make it easier to read the script.  I had this issue BEFORE I did this, it is my calling script that creates the lines that look like "Calling Site2 Outbound"  and the scripts they call have logging lines to give the lines that look like this:  "rsync Started HUB->Site2 Thu Mar 28 06:08:41 EDT 2019"

eg:  Master Script: (redacted and shortened)

```
#!/bin/sh   
foo=rsync-`date +%m%d%Y`.log    

echo 'Syncing remote sites to main site Started '`date` >> /data/Logs/$foo  
echo '------------------------------------------'>> /data/Logs/$foo 

echo 'Calling Site1 Inbound' >> /data/Logs/$foo 
    /bin/sh /root/SiteScripts/Site1In.sh $foo
echo ' '>> /data/Logs/$foo  

echo 'Calling Site2 Inbound' >> /data/Logs/$foo 
    /bin/sh /root/SiteScripts/Site2In.sh $foo
echo ' '>> /data/Logs/$foo  
.
. Rest of sites
.
echo ' '>> /data/Logs/$foo  
echo 'Syncing remote sites to main site Completed '`date` >> /data/Logs/$foo    
.
.
.
echo 'Syncing main site to remote sites Started'`date` >> /data/Logs/$foo   
echo '------------------------------------------'>> /data/Logs/$foo 

echo 'Calling Site1 Outbound' >> /data/Logs/$foo    
    /bin/sh /root/SiteScripts/Site1Out.sh $foo
echo ' '>> /data/Logs/$foo  

echo 'Calling Site2 Outbound' >> /data/Logs/$foo    
    /bin/sh /root/SiteScripts/Site2Out.sh $foo
echo ' '>> /data/Logs/$foo  

echo 'Calling Site3 Outbound' >> /data/Logs/$foo    
    /bin/sh /root/SiteScripts/Site3Out.sh $foo
echo ' '>> /data/Logs/$foo  

echo 'Syncing main site to remote sites Completed'`date` >> /data/Logs/$foo
```

Example of a Script That is called from above (just reverse for inbound)

```
#!/bin/sh   
echo 'rsync Started Hub->Site1 '`date` >> /data/Logs/$1 
    rsync -vzar --size-only --no-g --no-times --exclude "Subfolder/" --exclude "SubFolder/"  /data/OMSImage/* rsync://%Site1%/Image >> /data/Logs/$1
echo 'rsync Stopped Hub->Site1 '`date` >> /data/Logs/$1
```

========================================================================
4.2.2019 update.

I ran the sync again last evening now with an additional 'v' (-vvzari)
This is the full output I get.

```
Calling Site1 Outbound (.86)
rsync Started Hub -> Site1 Tue Apr 2 04:25:12 EDT 2019
opening tcp connection to 192.168.86.61 port 873
sending daemon args: --server -vvloDprze.iLsfxC "--log-format=%i" --size-only . IMAGES/  (6 args)
sending incremental file list
[sender] hiding directory 3d-Volumes because of pattern FOLDER1/
[sender] hiding directory Romexis3d because of pattern FOLDER2/
[sender] expand file_list pointer array to 524288 bytes, did move
[sender] expand file_list pointer array to 1048576 bytes, did move
[sender] expand file_list pointer array to 2097152 bytes, did move
[sender] expand file_list pointer array to 1439480 bytes, did move
rsync Stopped Hub -> Site1 Tue Apr 2 04:40:19 EDT 2019
```

It looks to me like RSYNC has enumerated the path, and sees no changes, but I know for sure there are 100's of new files.  Is there something that I am missing in the way RSYNC works?  I am only experiencing this issue in units where both ends have RSYNC 3.1.

Since my original post I have deployed a 4th NEW NAS unit, and I am experiencing the exact same issue with this one.   The remaining units are all old (5+ years) and I have no issues.

I am wondering now if I need to restart the RSYNC service on the HUB, or the Spokes for this to happen?

I will add a 3rd 'v' tonight.....

- I have created a new script that I am running in the AM from CRON, it only does the OUTBOUND to the failing devices, and it runs as expected.

4.5.2019 UPDATE.

After adding extra 'v' I have been able to do some more troubleshooting.
I have added an 'extra' NAS device.
Remember that I have the 'HUB' and it is 'pulling' all remote sites without any issues.
It will just not 'push' to all of my 'newer' NAS units.

I have added a second NAS (save hardware as the HUB called SPARENAS) to the physical location of the HUB.

I am did the following syncs for testing
        All IN to the 'HUB'
        The 'HUB' Sends to this new NAS (SpareNAS)
        The SpareNAS sends to the 'remote' NAS devices.

Here is the interesting part.

The HUB to the Spare = NO ISSUES.
The Spare to the Remote = SAME ISSUES.

This indicates to me that the issue is at the 'REMOTE' NAS devices.

I am going to do more testing, and my next step will be to use 'sshpass' to tell the failing 'REMOTE' NAS devices to restart Rsync after they are successfully 'pulled' from.

If this does not work I will use the same method to reboot the REMOTE nas device after the successful 'PULL'.

The Sync takes several hours so they will have plenty of time to boot before I try to access them again.

I think this has at least proven that the 'push' error is not at my 'HUB'.

Comment: New Information I forgot to mention and it might matter.  The scripts I have are all Cron Jobs,  but when I run them manually they are not.   I am going to do a few things, I am going to add an "i" to the command and read the output (it will be huge as a result)  Also the next time I have to 'manually' run the script I will do it in a Cron to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Don't use `.../*` as source, rsync is perfectly capable of expanding the path itself as you're using `-a` (note `-r` is redundant with `-a`). With `-v` you get more information about what rsync is doing, repeating the `v` increases verbosity. And what is "MWF"?

Comment: MWF = Monday Wednesday Friday.   TH = Tuesday Thursday.   Sorry...    In the past when I exclude the / it was making an entire new tree and copying everything.  I will test it without the / in my lab to see if there was some other error at that time.   I have been using these scripts for almost a year (with slight modifications since I had errors).

Comment: Update - I added an 'i' to the command for one of my sub scripts (-vzari) and it copied files as expected.   I am adding that to the others tonight to see if it fixes it.  I do not like the extra logging but if it makes it work it is worth it.

Comment: I wasn't talking about leaving out the `/`, I meant `*`. `-i` only affects the logging, it doesn't affect anything else. I expect something else changed

Comment: as for the 'i' I would agree. but I added it to 1 of the 3 and only that one worked.  so where I agree, I can see nothing else that changed.  I have added it to the others, no harm no foul.    I misunderstood your note, about the *.   Thanks again.

Comment: As expected the 'i' made no difference, I was hoping the extra logging would give me something but I still just get "sending incremental file list" and nothing else.  I would have expected more.  I am going to add another 'v' and see if I get more, that with the 'i' might give me something.  But it seems like it just never finishes or thinks all it good when I definitely have files that need to go 'out'.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the answer to this issue.
From other research I believe the issue is the Device I am using and the firmware.
I am using NETGEAR ReadyNas devices.
The ones that are having issues are using Firmware 6.9.5.
I have had other issues w/ SMB access being slow, and I have found that all the 6.9.x versions of the ReadyNas firmware have an issue with slow SMB, and Rsync (when used as a backup from the GUI) [Tons of posts about this on the NETGEAR forums].

[NETGEAR forum - Slow SMB](https://community.netgear.com/t5/Using-your-ReadyNAS-in-Business/Very-slow-copy-with-SMB/td-p/1401413)
[NETGEAR forum - Slow SMB after 6.9.x](https://community.netgear.com/t5/Using-your-ReadyNAS-in-Business/Slow-SMB-after-upgrade-to-6-9-x/td-p/1622097)

I am not using RSYNC in that way, but it seems I am having similar issues as others.

So even though my scripts did need tweaking and are running better and faster and not breaking permissions like they were a month ago, I am still having issues, but I think I cannot fix them.  I have to Wait for NETGEAR to fix them....